# IP address/ OS version and device key

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, mobilefirst-server

I have MobileFirst (V7.O) **Hybrid** app . How can I get the current IP address, OS version (android nnn, Iphone nnn), Device unique Id for the device. Basically, I am recording some information at various point in my app.

Can you please provide some hints and how to get this information

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be found deviceID &  IP address below information

unique deviceID

```
WL.Device.getID({onSuccess : function(o) { 
   alert(o.deviceID); 
}, onFailure : function(e) { 
WL.Logger.info("Error getting ID: " + e); 
}});
```

IP address

```
WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
    alert (networkInfo.ipAddress); 
});
```

Device OS version use cordova

```
var deviceVersion = device.version;
```

check cordova api https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/device/device.html

more this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-9